# Velocity same condition for all boolean in the template

Tags: java, templates, velocity

I'm new to Velocity, so I have a template with lot of boolean value.
And what I want is to define just once a condition who replace every "true" by "yes" and every "false" by "no". Cause I don't want to write the condition for each of my variable.

There is a way to do that ? in the begining of my template for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a macro:

```
#macro( formatboolean $booleanvalue )
  #if ( $booleanvalue ) yes #else no #end
#end
```

and use it in your template:

```
#formatboolean ( $myboolean )
```